# NameError when using Sage polynomials

Tags: python, sage, polynomials

I read [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html) how to work with polynomials. But when I try this

```
R = QQ['t']
poly = (t+1) * (t+2); poly
```

Sage gives me the following error:

```
NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you have to *inject* the variable name when using polynomial rings.  The document you point to points out that

```
sage: R.<t> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
```

*does* do this.  Or, you can do

```
sage: R=QQ['t']
sage: R.inject_variables()
Defining t
sage: t+1
t + 1
```

You wanted to know how to do it without printing the name:

```
sage: R.inject_variables(verbose=False)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much. I need my polynomials within a function. How can I prevent sage from printing "Defining t"? The log becomes pretty messy when many function are called.

Comment: Well, then the angle bracket notation avoids this... but updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer by @kcrisman, another way to go is:

```
sage: R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 't')
sage: t = R.gen()
```

Then `t` works as expected:

```
sage: (t+1) * (t+2)
t^2 + 3*t + 2
```

Note that the Sage syntax `R.<t> = ...` will work in a `.sage` file but not in a `.py` file, while the above works also in a `.py` file.

In a `.py` file you would first import `PolynomialRing` as follows:

```
from sage.rings.polynomial.polynomial_ring_constructor import PolynomialRing
```

To find out what imports you need, you can do

```
sage: import_statements(PolynomialRing)
from sage.rings.polynomial.polynomial_ring_constructor import PolynomialRing
```

Finally, if you don't need the ring `R`,
you can define `t` directly with

```
sage: t = polygen(QQ)
```

and if you ever need `R` later you can use

```
sage: R = t.parent()
```